# How to do action on Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Hello I am new to RxJava, I have a class that receives `Flowable<Item> f2`, I need to get values from it, without any data changed (saves values to local cache). Then concatenate it with other `Flowable f1` and send it to higher level class. Is it possible to emit values only once from `f2`?

Also how can I do action on all Items coming from `Flowable f1`, but after n Items create new `Flowable f2` from `f1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, `doOnNext()` is probably what you are looking for (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#doOnNext-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-).

```java
 private static void main() {
    Flowable<String> f2 = Flowable.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    Flowable<String> f1 = Flowable.just("z", "x", "y");

    f2.doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("saving " + n))
      .concatWith(f1)
      .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Flowable.timer(10, SECONDS) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

For your second question, it depends if you want to get rid of the items after the nth one. If so, you can use `take()`, if not you may have look at `buffer()`.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flowable<String> f1 = Flowable.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    Flowable<String> f2 = Flowable.just("z", "x", "y");


    f1.doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("action on " + n))
      .take(3)
      .subscribe(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("Other possible use case:");
    System.out.println("------------------------");

    f1.doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("another action on " + n))
      .buffer(3)
      .flatMap(l -> Flowable.fromIterable(l).map(s -> "Hello " + s))
      .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Flowable.timer(10, SECONDS) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

You can have a look at the RxJava javadoc of `Flowable` (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/index.html?io/reactivex/Flowable.html). It has lots of operators and marble diagrams explains very well what each operator does.